# Rails 4 Apache2 phusion app in production mode

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, production

I dont know if my app is in production or development mode, when I put rake about in console it say "Environment production" but the app write in log/development.log and the app put errors trace in the browser or if you put a bad route, the app put all routes in the browser like a development mode.

bundle exec rake about

About your application's environment

> Rails version             4.2.4
>
> Ruby version              2.1.2-p95 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
>
> RubyGems version          2.2.2
>
> Rack version              1.6.4
>
> JavaScript Runtime        therubyracer (V8)
>
> Middleware                Rack::Sendfile, Rack::Lock, , Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, RequestStore::Middleware, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, Warden::Manager
>
> Application root          /var/www/clients/client3/web37
>
> Environment               production
>
> Database adapter          mysql2
>
> Database schema version   20160205114313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to check following setting in your application:

when we deploy Rails application with Passenger + Apache then Passenger by default set it's **RailsEnv to production(RailsEnv production)**. you need to check in you apache conf file rails enviromnet is set at production or not. like:

```
#web_app vhost setting
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com 
 DocumentRoot  /var/www/apps/web_app/public   
 RailsEnv production
<Directory /var/www/apps/web_app/public>    
     AllowOverride all        
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews   
     Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

set ***chmod 755*** on the root of Rails application, made sure the ***production.log*** existed and that it had at least ***chmod 0666*** privileges.

Comment: Ok thnks now it's in production.